# MVC3, the buildmanager, and triggering recompilation when views change

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a question about the MVC3 view page activator and how changes to the views trigger recompilation.  There seems to be some magic going on in BuildManager that I can’t see because the source code is not available for the symbols -- and even reflector can’t see inside.

What I’ve done is implement my own VPP and subclass of the Razor view engine for purposes of displaying razor views that do not live on the filesystem.  My mock setup just returns data from a string to render.  This works fine, but what does not work is when you change that data, the class is not recompiled. And it is not clear how to get either RazorBuildProvider or BuildManager to regenerate the c# code and recompile it when the data returned from the VPP is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your VPP you need to override the [`GetCacheDependency()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.virtualpathprovider.getcachedependency.aspx) method, from which you need to return an appropriate [`CacheDependency`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cachedependency.aspx) object. Take a look at its constructor for things that can be monitored (like files or directories). You can also use [`SqlCacheDependency`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.sqlcachedependency.aspx) if your file contents lives in a SQL Server instance.

Comment: That was the clue I was looking for! I followed this [guide](http://books.google.com/books?id=cND87IlQ9WMC&pg=PA481&lpg=PA481&dq=custom%2Bcache%2Bdependency&source=bl&ots=TSfH1sHw7b&sig=%5FPILUBm1TRfy0Nr2ZJXYKrEf4II&hl=en&ei=w0QASvDZKYb6%5FAawzYDzBg&sa=X&oi=book%5Fresult&ct=result&resnum=9#v=onepage&q=custom%2Bcache%2Bdependency&f=false) to implement a subclass of CacheDependency to detect when the in-memory data had changed, which was what I needed for my POC. Problem solved!

Answer (score 2):

While GetCacheDependency is indeed the way it works by default (and marcind points out), it's often not possible to come up with a CacheDependency object when using custom file stores.

Instead, what you need to do is return null from GetCacheDependency. But you *do* need to implement GetFileHash to make the invalidation work correctly. The hash you return needs to be based on the content of all the files.

Whenever you return a hash that is different from what it was last time the page was queried, the page will end up getting recompiled.

Of course, you should make sure that if files *don't* change you keep returning the same hash, otherwise the page will keep getting recompiled, making things extremely slow.